# unable to migrate database on production while running rake task

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, scheduled-tasks

i am developing a small app which will 
download a csv file(from a give url) everyday and inject the data(in csv file) to database and load the same data in the webview. its working perfect in my local system.but when i deployed to heroku database injection from csv file is not working.

here is my code.

downloader.rake file

```
namespace :downloader do
desc "download a file"
task:downloading => :environment do
Rails.logger.info("message from task")
Download.destroy_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE from sqlite_sequence where name = 'downloads'")
#**********some other code ************
end
end
```

schedule.rb file

```
set :environment, 'production'

every 1.minutes do
rake "downloader:downloading"
end
```

when i run it in production it shows in log($tail -f log/production.log)

```
D, [2015-07-21T12:17:02.910529 #11740] DEBUG -- :   Download Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "downloads".* FROM "downloads"
E, [2015-07-21T12:17:02.910635 #11740] ERROR -- : SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: downloads: SELECT "downloads".* FROM "downloads"
```

Comment: Have you tried heroku rake db:migrate (Please check command)? What error it throws while migrating data on heroku?

Comment: it worked fine..didnt show any error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your database is not ready on Heroku.

Please veryify to have installed a mysql database for your application and then run `heroku run db:setup` to build the schema and seed it.

Comment: when i run heroku run rake db:setup it shows  FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

Comment: Are you using sqllite or postgresl? Anyway, did you installed a database for your app on heroku?   `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

Comment: still it showing same problem when i run `heroku run rake db:setup`    after running above command                  _FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"_
_DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege._                                           _Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",.......................}_

Comment: Maybe `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL`

Comment: it worked fine...but still getting same error on `setup` command  .....thanks for reply

Comment: What if you run `heroku run rake db:schema:load`?

Comment: its working...it created the tables in app...i migrated the database to heroku..but still not updating the data in webview.....

Comment: Well, your query is explicitly for sqllite so probably is not working properly

Comment: you mean above sql query?

Comment: I mean `"DELETE from sqlite_sequence where name = 'downloads'"` will clearly not work in postgres

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83945/discussion-between-vjnan369-and-coorasse).